# What does the + and - sign do in datePicker options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I just was going through the **[datetimepicker Docs](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)** examples and came across the following example:

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
 timepicker:false,
 formatDate:'Y/m/d',
 minDate:'-1970/01/02',//yesterday is minimum date(for today use 0 or -1970/01/01)
 maxDate:'+1970/01/02'//tomorrow is maximum date calendar
});
```

Now i am aware that the `Date()` in javascript functions as follows:

> Creates a JavaScript Date instance that represents a single moment in
>   time. Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of
>   milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC.

But why the + and - signs at the beginning of the dates ?? like so:

```
minDate:'-1970/01/02',//yesterday is minimum date(for today use 0 or -1970/01/01)
maxDate:'+1970/01/02'//tomorrow is maximum date calendar
```

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it was correct?

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at the [code on github](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/blob/master/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js#L1973) and did some debugging, and it looks like it does what the comments say. A `+` sign will give you tomorrow and a `-` sign will give you yesterday. It's not clear to me why `1970/01/02` is getting treated as a special value to mean today when using the plus or minus sign. But it does work. If you specify `+1972/01/02` instead of `+1970/01/02` you will get "tommorrow" plus two years.

Comment: Thanks ... you said `+1972/01/02` will give tomorrow ... do u mean `+1970/01/02` ?

Comment: I said `+1972/01/02` will give tomorrow plus 2 years.